# AWS CodeStar GitHub Enterprise Connection Fails with ProviderResourceNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-enterprise, aws-codestar

I'm encountering an error when attempting to connect AWS CodeStar to a GitHub Enterprise Server instance hosted on AWS. The initial steps including setting up the host connection and installing the AWS application seem to work without issues. However, when I try to finalize the connection by updating the pending connection, I receive the following error:

```
ProviderResourceNotFoundException Installation 9 does not exist
```

[image]

Steps already tried without success:

- Reinstalling the connection
- Reinstalling the AWS app
- Granting additional permissions

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide insights on resolving this error?